# How do I share latitude & longitute of a starred location in Google Maps?

Tags: gps, google-maps

The question title speaks for itself. How the heck do I do that in Google Maps. If I try to share a starred location, I get a link but not the coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

This is bit long, round about and bit approximate way.  Other than this method, I do not know any other way.

In Google maps, press menu, goto Settings->About->Map centre.  The value showed as map center is the coordinate of the place at the centre of the screen.  So, you may have to align the starred place to centre of the screen and do this sequence to get it's coordinates.  This will only be as accurate as you can position the starred place at the centre. The accuracy can be improved by zooming in.

It will be nice if somebody comes up with a better idea.